# Can I render the animation inside SCNView without adding it to the superview?

Tags: swift, scenekit, sceneview

I have a task: to make a 3d object animated in SCNScene and do frame by frame scnView.snapshot() without adding SCNView to any subview. If I add SCNView to  the subview - then everything works fine. But without adding it does not work. How can I start and manage this rendering?

I tried to scnView.sceneTime += 1 and call play() function - but no reaction. The same with isPlaying = true. Maybe the display calls some protocols for the scnView when display the scnView, but I can't find any of them to call this functions manually.

Answer (score 0):

There's some workaround that you can use to cheat your app. It's the layer's opacity. Even if the contents of the SCNView is invisible, you'll still be capable of taking snapshots.

```
self.view.addSubview(sceneView!)
sceneView?.layer?.opacity = 0.0
```

Comment: the main issue that I can't use `self.view.addSubview(sceneView!)`. Because I work with plugin and there no `self.view`